# Getting files from Ubuntu to Windows via VMware

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I have files in Ubuntu which is running via VMware that I need to get to my Windows host machine.  How do I transfer these files if I don't have VMware Tools installed?

Comment: Just as long as your Ubuntu OS is on the network, you can install SSH server on Ubuntu, Use Putty SSH client for Windows. This is not a programming related question.

Comment: Putty itself doesn't do file transfers. He'd need PScp for that. I recommend WinSCP because it's friendlier. I agree about this being the wrong site for this question, but I don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

Start up an `sshd`, `ftpd` or `tftpd` service in the Ubuntu system; then you can use `WinScp`, an FTP client or a tFTP client from your Windows box to transfer files. You only need to know the IP address for your Linux box as seen from the Windows box.

You could also set up `samba` in Linux so you could access the Linux machine's drives as Windows shares, but I had so many hassles last time I tried that, I chose to go for one of the other options.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple one:

I use [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) to transfer files by installing the client on both the host and guest OS. Of course, this gets squiffy when I need to move big files, but it's dead simple.

Comment: Heh, when I'm desperate but in a hurry and have at least browser access in both systems, I occasionally just email files to myself via my Gmail account ;) Similar considerations about file size, of course.

Comment: I like the 'gmail as a poor man's ftp' suggestion!